# How to solve element type error in android stuido

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, xml-parsing

I am receiving this error for few days and did not get any solution. is there any way to solve it, please?
Error:
Parse Error at [row, col]:[30,7]
Message: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

### XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### AndroidManifist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
      <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

Comment: I tried your xml code and I don't see any problem. May be you can clean and build the project again.

Comment: @akhilnair i have tried manuy times but got same result

Comment: Do you have just two xml files in your whole project?

Comment: @akhilnair yes only these two

Comment: Now am really not sure because I don't see any problem when I use your code. Check for some white spaces in your xml files or create a new project and paste these xml files there and see if the issue still persists.